probrema con fullcalendar en asp.net core 8 mvc con JSON
Soy novata, alguien que me explique que estoy haciendo mal ya que no puedo mostrar los eventos en el full calendar e probado de distintas maneras y nada; para darme a entender, los eventos los obtengo por medio de un procedimiento almacenado la cual necesita parámetros de entrada para ejecutarse.
el procedimiento lo realiza correctamente el problema radica al momento de mostrar los resultados dentro del calendario.
este es mi controlador:
public async Task<JsonResult> GetEjecutarProcedimiento(DateTime? FechaInicio = null, DateTime? FechaFin = null, int? EquiposXDia = null)
{
    var events = new List<TempCalendar>();
    using (var connection = (SqlConnection)_mantenimientoContext.Database.GetDbConnection())
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("CalendarizacionMantenimiento", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FechaInicio", @FechaInicio));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FechaFin", @FechaFin));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EquiposXDia", EquiposXDia));

            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    events.Add(new TempCalendar
                    {
                        Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        title = reader.GetString(1) + reader.GetInt32(3) + reader.GetInt32(4),
                        Start = reader.GetDateTime(2)
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Json(events);
}


esta es la vista:
 <script>

     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
         var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

         var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
             headerToolbar: {
                 left: 'prev,next today',
                 center: 'title',
                 right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
             },
             defaultDate: new Date,
             locale: 'es',
             navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
             businessHours: true, // display business hours
             editable: true,
             selectable: true,
             events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                 req.get('calendario/GetEjecutarProcedimiento')
                     .type('Json')
                     .query({
                         start: info.start.valueOf(),
                         end: info.end.valueOf()
                     })
                     .end(function (err, res) {

                         if (err) {
                             failureCallback(err);
                         } else {

                             successCallback(
                                 Array.prototype.slice.call( // convert to array
                                     res.getElementsByTagName('event')
                                 ).map(function (eventEl) {
                                     return {
                                         title: eventEl.getAttribute('title'),
                                         start: eventEl.getAttribute('start')
                                     }
                                 })
                             )
                         }
                     })

                 defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                     eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                         alert(calEvent.title);
                     }
             });

         calendar.render();
     });

 </script>
</div>

resultado:
 {
   "id": 1,
   "title": "informatica",
   "start": "2024-07-11T00:00:00",
   "descripcion1": 0,
   "descripcion2": 0
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "title": "finanzas",
   "start": "2024-07-12T00:00:00",
   "descripcion1": 0,
   "descripcion2": 0
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "title": "ventas",
   "start": "2024-07-13T00:00:00",
   "descripcion1": 0,
   "descripcion2": 0
 }]

obtengo los resultados en un archivo y no en el calendario.

¿Cual sería el resultado correcto?

Pon en el título de la pregunta el problema específico que estás teniendo. Lee [ask]. Además, dale el formato correcto a tu código agregando triples acentos graves (backticks, ```) una línea antes y una después de tal bloque de código.

Te dejé un título un poquito más acorde al problema. Edita la pregunta y agrega los detalles que consideres necesarios para que cualquiera pueda entender bien lo que te está ocurriendo y sea más sencillo poder guiarte.

el resultado correcto seria mostrar los eventos en el día correspondiente en el calendario
